# A String variable obtained by using re search cannot be printed if used with %

Tags: python

I have a python script which searches and extracts a particular snippet of string from the output of a command.

```
def runCmd():
    ...

stdout, stderr = runCmd(cmd)
match = re.search(r'Selector: (.*)', stdout)
selector = match.group(1)
selector = selector.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '+')

print selector
```

Now the problem is, if I print the variable 'selector', it prints properly, showing the string extracted from stdout. However, if I use print statement in below fashion, the variable does not print.

```
print 'Selector Found : ', selector, type(selector)
print 'Selector Found : %s' % selector, type(selector)
```

The output from the above print statements is just `<type 'str'>`.

Why the other things, like `'Selector Found : '` and the variable contents are not getting printed?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see `selector` printed you are misunderstanding something about your program and your `selector` value is empty now. You can use `repr()` or `%r` to print a *Python representation* of the value:

```
print 'Selector Found:', repr(selector), type(selector)
print 'Selector Found: %r' % selector, type(selector)
```

The representation of a string uses Python string literal notation; you can paste the result back into a Python script or interpreter to recreate the same value. If it is an empty string, `''` will be printed.

Your command likely returned nothing but whitespace after `'Selector: '`.

Comment: Hi Martijn, sorry I missed typing %s in the question. In my code I have used %s. Also, what about the first print command, why is it not printing?  print 'Selector Found : ', selector, type(selector)

Comment: @hem: add a `print repr(selector)` before those or use `%r` instead of `%s`; your `selector` value is most likely **empty**.